# trouble installing ruby rest-client

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I recently tried to install rest-client on Ruby, in order to follow along with a tutorial, and I get the error that I will post down below. I've successfully installed DevKit. When I input gem -v, command prompt returns 2.2.5. The entirety of the error is down below.

```
Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.
beta2/ext/gems/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.beta2/ext/gems/ex
tensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/gem_make.out
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `bl
ock in build'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `bu
ild'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 l
evels) in build_extension'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in b
uild_extension'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchroniz
e'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_exte
nsion'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in b
uild_extensions'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_exte
nsions'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:677:in `build_extens
ions'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:232:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:78:in `
install'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:206:in `block in i
nstall_into'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:198:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:198:in `install_in
to'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:119:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:389:in `i
nstall'
        from mkrf_conf.rb:15:in `<main>'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/unf-0.2.0.
beta2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/unf
-0.2.0.beta2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Have you checked what is logged in `C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/unf
-0.2.0.beta2/gem_make.out` ?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use Windows for Ruby/Rails development, since many gems just don't work on that platform. Get some Unix OS, Linux or Mac both will do.

Comment: Alexey,  

thank you for the advice. Right now I'm in the begenning stages of Ruby and don't want to go through the hassle of installing a flavor of Linux on my ssd (apparently it is not as simple as installing Linux dual-boot on a traditional hd). Does rest-client not work on windows, specifically Windows 8.1?

Comment: @Alexey Shein It's generally not a nice idea to tell users that they should use a different operating system. the user may have valid reasons for their choice.

Comment: I have a version on rest-client installed on windows 7, but for an older ruby version. I see in the code on github that there is a file called rest-client.windows.gemspec So it should be possible.